# How can I kill all jobs of a user without logging out?

Tags: bash, ssh, server

Currently, I use this command:

`pkill -u username`

But this also logs me out of the server.

How can I kill all the jobs belonging to a user without logging out?

Comment: How could that possibly *not* log you out? `bash` is a job. Your X server and windowing session are jobs. If you aren't logged out, by definition, not all your jobs were killed.

Answer (score 0):

This is obsolete and unportable but works for me in debian.

```
skill -u username
```